# Parent Controller function doesn't get called

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a form like this :

```
<form name="form.ProjectForm" ng-submit="setProject()" >

                <label for="titre">Titre du projet</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="titre" placeholder="Titre" ng-model="project.name" restrict access="guest">
             <div class="horizontal-scroll" ng-controller="SmartTableController">
              <table class="table" st-table="displayedData" st-safe-src="smartTableData" >
                <thead>
                <tr class="sortable ">
                  <th class="table-id" st-sort="id" st-sort-default="true">#</th>
                  <th st-sort="firstname">Prénom</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th></th>
                  <th><input st-search="firstname" placeholder="Chercher Prénom" class="input-sm form-control search-input"
                             type="search"/></th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in displayedData">
                  <td class="table-id">{{item.id}}</td>
                  <td>{{item.firstname}}</td>
                  <td><label class="checkbox-inline custom-checkbox nowrap">
                         <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" ng-change="Selected(item.id,checkStatus)" ng-model='checkStatus' />
                          </label>
                   </td>  
                </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
</form>
```

And In my **Project controller** :

```
    $scope.Selected= function(selectedId, checkStatus){
      if(checkStatus == false) {
        var index = $scope.selectedUsers.indexOf(selectedId);
        $scope.selectedUsers.splice(index, 1);
      }else{
        $scope.selectedUsers.push(selectedId);
      }
    };
```

And this is my state definition :

```
 .state('projects', {
            url: '/projects',
            template : '<ui-view  autoscroll="true" autoscroll-body-top></ui-view>',
            abstract: true,
            title: 'Les projets',
            controller : 'ProjectController',
            controllerAs : 'pCtrl',
            sidebarMeta: {
                icon: 'ion-compose',
                order: 250,
            },
        })
        .state('projects.add', {
            url: '/add',
            templateUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/gestionprojet/projects',
            title: 'Ajouter un projet',
            sidebarMeta: {
                order: 800,
            },
        })
```

But the `$scope.Selected` function isn't called.And I've tried controllerAs but it dosn't work either.

Any help will be appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: add `ng-controller` in the form element instead of particular input.

Comment: You mean smartController?

Comment: yes `SmartTableController`

Comment: You aren't using `controllerAs` syntax in view or in controller but you declare `controllerAs` in routing config

Comment: Yeah because I tried `pCtrl.Selected()` and it didn't work so I removed it